# Is it possible to roll back a flatpak update?

Tags: flatpak

Question in the title... A recent flatpak update to an application has introduced new bugs that turnou to be a bigger nuisance that the bugs that are fixed.

I don't see anything that looks like a `flatpak rollback` command, but is there a reasonably safe manual procedure?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(from the Flatpak docs)

**Downgrading**

It is possible to downgrade an installed application (or runtime) to an older build.

First you look for the commit you are interested in; this example is with GIMP:

```
$ flatpak remote-info --log flathub org.gimp.GIMP

GNU Image Manipulation Program - Create images and edit photographs

        ID: org.gimp.GIMP
       Ref: app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable
      Arch: x86_64
    Branch: stable
   Version: 2.10.14
   License: GPL-3.0+ AND LGPL-3.0+
Collection: org.flathub.Stable
  Download: 108.9 MB
 Installed: 308.1 MB
   Runtime: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.32

       Sdk: org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/3.32
    Commit: 8003d469b2224a1abe54b45793c9692e822cacee860d94861f5fc5e43111a689
    Parent: 3fdfdf0963ba67629f287092229d9f5659bc9a2eeb1158c060b09d8a603acbcf
   Subject: Fix CPU detection on GEGL build. (3b047adf)
      Date: 2019-10-30 00:56:11 +0000
   History: 

    Commit: 3fdfdf0963ba67629f287092229d9f5659bc9a2eeb1158c060b09d8a603acbcf
   Subject: Fix typo! (a752f7df)
      Date: 2019-09-02 20:28:05 +0000

    Commit: 798d8cd8a6a2ccf1bf21c0f5e9749dd4d97ecd511a3af1922d6fedf6c26e3a7c
   Subject: Release GIMP 2.10.12! (1366fa63)
      Date: 2019-06-13 02:25:52 +0000

    Commit: 451758521226112dd7d4e2c4ce7fadaa93f69ce58c2f1afb70fb057db81f5e57
   Subject: Update to GEGL 0.4.16. (1d8cb1dd)
      Date: 2019-05-09 05:02:52 +0000

    Commit: 5c8a3dc204a12d4695c5bb7e98ea3b3862d78e52c1cf0f9b021c1dae836ecc95
   Subject: Build GTK+2 with more patches. (d7578706)
      Date: 2019-04-25 16:46:42 +0000

    Commit: fdbcfcbb8e5a4a6f484674208c6bbdf96c6e37fe2df21983a444069e5949276f
   Subject: Release GIMP 2.10.10! (781c0f7c)
      Date: 2019-04-07 21:40:06 +0000

    Commit: 81dc4a6595d81ef6fe7b563dc046cf6dec2856a9628c1b8ff3178bf0547e6490
   Subject: Update some dependencies. (8cef7f17)
      Date: 2019-04-04 18:14:23 +0000

    Commit: d0d12223774157ce64690d7096624741bdadc9490ac730ee2aa752eabf2ce0b1
   Subject: Downgrade ibus from shared-modules (d5d82037)
      Date: 2019-04-03 20:07:35 +0000

    Commit: 1c130cbfaec924ee87a98f541b451f8e527599b2efda3add51cb0f57b3806ac5
   Subject: Add "org.freedesktop.FileManager1" bus access. (bbf1f104)
      Date: 2019-01-08 19:51:49 +0000

    Commit: 1fcb2c783cf61e22ca6ed03df9f95d59785d5cbd668b50f9765693956f1eedeb
   Subject: Update babl dependency. (e7b662db)
      Date: 2018-11-16 22:41:23 +0000

    Commit: b6186ed16c732603f5c317bbc42717e500c0077251f9e8035a3266924b9cd55b
   Subject: Release GIMP 2.10.8. (34b1d53c)
      Date: 2018-11-09 13:49:13 +0000

    Commit: 0edfacfb334969b2fd5dc8d02cb1f0a5a98a833b24fdc6bb25ba3fb042df08a9
   Subject: Update babl and GEGL. (efaecfbb)
      Date: 2018-10-27 23:52:37 +0000
```

So, if you wanted to go back to v2.10.8, you'd deploy this commit:

```
$ flatpak update \
--commit=ec07ad6c54e803d1428e5580426a41315e50a14376af033458e7a65bfb2b64f0 \
org.gimp.GIMP
```

UPDATE: as [Syco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/50403/syco) commented, using `flatpak mask org.gimp.GIMP` would prevent GIMP from being updated the next time you ran `flatpak update`; this was introduced in `flatpak` v1.5, just a few weeks before I answered this post.

Note that you can list the current masks using `flatpak mask`.

Also consider using the `--user` option depending upon the install location.

Comment: If you're not sure what the Application ID is, use `flatpak search <NAME>`. For example `flatpak search gimp`. And to "unmask" the app in the future, `flatpak mask --remove org.gimp.Gimp`

Comment: I think it should be `flatpak update ...`, **without the `sudo`**. Else you'd be updating the root's packages.

Comment: somehow some package not listing the version in the commit, can we listing commit id with the detailed version?