# How to inhibit update of flatpak?

Tags: flatpak

I use a specific flatpak app, [downgraded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552688/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-a-flatpak-update) to a version that runs stable. My fedora system (33) routinely upgrades the app.
How can I tell flatpak to never update a specific package/app?

Answer (score 1):

The command is

```
 flatpak mask org.some.App
```

see `man flatpak-mask` for instructions on the command.

https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/2834 and https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/pull/3130 provide you with the history to this command.

Comment: On my system, `flatpak install [ref]` defaults to `--user`, contrary to the man page which says it defaults to `--system`. But `flatpak mask` defaults to `--system`, so I have to add the `--user` flag. Not sure how or why it's set up this way.